# getting error message: "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\paymentController] does not exist after hosting on server

Tags: laravel, controller, razorpay

I am getting this error after hosted it on server on network tab i am currently using laravel 7.6.

> message: "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\paymentController] does not exist.",…}
> exception: "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException"
> file: "/home4/helthr4e/public_html/trainer.helthofit.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php"
> line: 807

Comment: show your controller and where you are getting this error

Comment: Probably a typo in ``routes/web.php`` or in the controller class.

Comment: i think here is the problem .host in sensitive to uppercase and lowercase and you wrote paymentController
change it to PaymentController and test it again

Comment: i think problem in the Controller name  or namespace please recheck them

Comment: Route::get('/home/subscribe/{amount}', 'HomeController@subscribePlan');
Route::post('/paysuccess', 'paymentController@paysuccess');

Comment: Route::get('/home/subscribe/{amount}', 'HomeController@subscribePlan');
Route::post('/paysuccess', 'paymentController@paysuccess');

Comment: <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth,DB;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{

Comment: public function payment()
    {
        $api_key= 'key';
        $api_secret= 'Secret';
        $api = new Api($api_key, $api_secret);
        $order  = $api->order->create(array('receipt' => '123', 'amount' => 100, 'currency' => 'INR')); // Creates order
        $orderId = $order['id']; 
    }

Comment: i share my routes and controller code above please help me

Answer (score 0):

i think here is the problem:

1- your namespaces are not correct - check them again

2- host and server are sensitive to uppercase and lowercase and you wrote `paymentController`

change it to `PaymentController` and test it again

**added:**
change your route to :  `Route::post('/paysuccess', 'PaymentController@paysuccess')`

Comment: Route::get('/home/subscribe/{amount}', 'HomeController@subscribePlan');
Route::post('/paysuccess', 'paymentController@paysuccess');

Comment: shoe your controller code 

specially controller namespace

Comment: here is your problem.in controller your controller name is PaymentController but you are calling it in web.php like paymentController.
is i said host is sensitive to uppercase and lowercase